# About Zoe Barnes in the second season of House of Cards

Tags: house-of-cards

All of us were frightened about the final destiny of Zoe in the second season of [*House of Cards*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1856010/). But after the scene I was wondering... how could Frank escape from the crime scene without any witnesses (cameras or security systems)? The subway station wasn't empty and it seems nobody tried to do something but declared it as "accident" (in the news). I know that they were in a blind spot, but still, for me, it is not very realistic that nobody noticed a suspicious person running away.

I've only watched the first episode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He starts walking as soon as he pushes her, and he's halfway up the stairs by the time bystanders notice she's under the train. He walks quickly but calmly, he doesn't run away. In unremarkable clothing, it isn't strange that no one stopped him.

As for security systems, if you watch more of the series, you'll notice that Frank is always aware of when he is being recorded. I don't believe his action was spur of the moment. He chose to meet her there and do the deed because he had an way out where any recording of him wouldn't be enough to identify him, especially with the hat and glasses. Would that be possible in the real world? Could there actually be a blind spot all the way out of the station? Unclear.

Her death was likely ruled an accident because metro police departments are overworked, and there isn't any immediate evidence to the contrary. The fact that they wouldn't find the angle and direction of her fall suspicious bother me too, I don't have an answer for that.

Comment: And Security Systems? , why declaring as an accident?

Comment: @Jean Paul Olvera: Later, Lucas asks the police man the same questions. He shows Lucas the video from the secutry camera and the place where they met is hidden.

Also, at a very late moment in the season, someone (I can't remember who) is shown having a photo of the security place with Frank and a post it note haveing a question mark on it.

Comment: (late to the game) Frank also takes the time to turn Zoe around, having her face the track so it looks like she does so intentionally dive (or even accidentally fall) face first as opposed to back first.  If she went in back first then, it could've been argued from the footage that she was pushed.

Comment: This answer lacks only the fact that previously in HoC, there were a scene of Frank holding a plan of the subway. He clearly planned the whole thing through before taking action.

Comment: It all adds up well until you focus on the fact that he relied 100% on his trust to Zoe having deleted his contact info from her phone. He didn't see her do it. That was what actually didn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

But I'm sure they would have pulled the recordings leading up to the incident. Obviously that particular spot by the fence they were talking out was a blind spot but it's not rocket science to rewind footage of several different cameras and follow the individual into the blind spot for a possible ID. Regardless if Francis was wearing a hat or not they could easily bring him in for questions especially after the allegations from the reporters.

Same with Russo. I'm pretty sure the cops could have gathered surveillance from outside the police station where Francis and Doug met him to see clearly he wasn't alone. And I'm pretty sure the parking garage had cameras and would have  captured a lone man wandering the parking garage right after the apparent suicide.

Sorry but I'm just not buying it.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest PLOT HOLE: Camera might have captured Zoe Barns leaning onto the fence while she is toying with her cell phone (deleting her messages and FU's number), and taking to someone (to FU) just few seconds before the accident (the murder). This was enough evidence to suspect that someone was there who might have pushed her in front of the coming train.